# Domains and set notation (with working)

Tags: calculus, functions

[image]
This is my working/how I've answered the question. However, does anyone know how I would state the domain of each function using set notation?

My working:

For g(x), the domain is when the inside of the square root is greater than or equal to zero.
Thus, x² - 1 ≥ 0
x² ≥ 1
Upon taking the square root of both sides, we result in:
x ≥ 1 or x ≤ -1 (the principle square root gets the positive, and the secondary square root gets the negative with the inequality sign flipped).

Thus, this function g(x) has the domain:

{x such that -1 ≥ x ≥ 1 }
Or alternatively, 
{x such that |x| ≥ 1}

With regards to f(x), the domain of the cosine function are all real numbers. The domain of a composite function is the domain which satisfies each individual function.

Thus, the domain of the composite function is:
{x such that |x| ≥ 1}

Comment: It is correct, now do the b)!

Answer (score 3):

If $f,~~g$ are functions such that $f\circ g$ be a function so

> $$\text{dom}(f\circ g)\subseteq \text{dom}(g)$$ and $$\text{dom}(f\circ g)=\text{dom}(g)\ \Longleftrightarrow \text{rang}(g)\subseteq \text{dom}(f)$$

Comment: I will give him +1 so that he have 33,333

Comment: Now, Congratulations 33,333 reputation with 3 kinds of badges including 3 gold one:D

Comment: @Mahdi Khosrav And his answer has 3 upvotes (at the moment).

Comment: And all numbers of his badges are divisible by 3.

Comment: +1 & Lots of supportive comments for you dear friend :^)